# Is my code for measuring "Form Submit" event in Google Analytics for contact form "Submit" button on correct?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, analytics, contact-form-7, gtag.js

I want to track "Submit Form" event for contact form of a website in Google Analytics. I don't want to use Google Tag Manager.

Is my code correct to track Form submit event that will trigger on "Submit" button of contact form? Is the function "onSubmit" correct or should I use "onClick" function?

I have Universal Google Analytics code with gtag function embedded in the website.
I have also created the Goal in Google Analytics and set the respective parameters for onSubmit event.

```
OnClick Event
onClick="gtag('event', 'submit', {'event_category': form', 'event_label': 'form submission'});"

OnSubmit Event
onSubmit="gtag('event', 'submit', {'event_category': form', 'event_label': 'form submission'});"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using contact form 7, if your theme has an admin theme option for adding script to the `<head></head>` section of your site, add the following code snippet

```
    <script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    gtag('event', 'submit', {'event_category': form', 'event_label': 'form submission'});
    }, false );
    </script>
```

If your theme does not offer an admin option for adding script to your sites, use a plugin such as Insert Header Footer Scripts from wordpress.org
or alternatively, create a function using wp_head and add it to your active theme's function.php file (not recommended, goes against WP best practices of not editing core theme files - unless you are using a child theme in which case add the function to your child theme functions.php file)

ref: https://contactform7.com/tracking-form-submissions-with-google-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

It will be onclick as like mention below:

```
<input id=”contact-submit” class=”button” type=”submit” value=”Submit” onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Form', eventAction: 'Submit', eventLabel: 'Contact'});">
```